# The minimum number of Hamiltonian paths in a strongly connected tournament of order $n$

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, directed-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

For $n\ge3$ let $a(n)$ be the minimum number of [Hamiltonian paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) in a strong (i.e., [strongly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)) [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) of order $n.$

> Where is $a(n)$ discussed in the literature? Is the exact value known? If not, what nontrivial bounds are known?

**My attempt:** (It is assumed throughout that $n\ge3.$)

**(I)** $a(n)$ is always odd.

This is because of [Rédei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_R%C3%A9dei)'s theorem, that a tournament has an odd number of Hamiltonian paths.

**(II)** $a(n+1)\ge a(n)+n-1.$

This follows easily from the fact that every strong tournament of order $n+1$ contains a cycle of length $n.$

**(III)** $\lfloor(n-1)^2/2\rfloor+1\le a(n)\le3\cdot2^{n-4}+3.$

These are the **trivial bounds**. The lower bound (which happens to be [OEIS sequence A099392](http://oeis.org/A099392)) follows from **(II)** by induction. For $n\gt4,$ the upper bound ([OEIS sequence A060013](http://oeis.org/A060013)) is achieved by taking the transitive tournament with vertices $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and edges $v_iv_j\ (i\lt j),$ and reversing the edges $v_1v_3$ and $v_2v_n.$

**(IV)** $a(3)=3,\ a(4)=5,\ a(5)=9,\ a(6)\in\{13,15\}.$

That's all I know. I already asked [this question on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688155/minimum-number-of-hamiltonian-paths-in-a-strongly-connected-tournament-on-n-no) without result.

Comment: The answer is about $5^{n/3}$. Reference: A note on the number of hamiltonian paths in strong tournaments, Arthur H. Busch.

Comment: The link to the freely available paper is http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v13i1n3. I am surprised such precise results are known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Arthur H. Busch](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v13i1n3) proved that the answer is about $5^{n/3}$.

Comment: The exact sequence starts 3,5,9,15,25,45,75,125... which is indeed in the OEIS (http://oeis.org/A005517) but not as "minimum number of hamilton paths in a strongly-connected tournament" but rather as "Smallest label $f(T)$ given to a rooted tree $T$ with $n$ nodes in Matula-Goebel labelling. But I bet they're the same.